# how I can install kedo on AKS with a windows node

Tags: windows, kubernetes, containers

I need to install "kedo" in an AKS that contains a windows node. When I install it, it is installed on the windows node and not on the Linux one. I have already tried various ways like

```
helm install keda kedacore/keda --namespace keda `
    --set nodeSelector:"beta\.kubernetes\.io\/os"=linux
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIFyN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct command to following

```
helm install keda kedacore/keda --namespace keda `
    --set nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```